# Placing button over ListView expands beyond page

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin Forms project. In xaml, I would like to have ListView and over it a button that will be clickable and transparent (Opacity=0.9). There is one label above ListView and one label below it. I used RelativeLayout to place ListView and transparent button and wrapped it inside StackLayout with two labels. Problem is ListView expands beyond page.

Here is my code for xaml file:

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#4d4d4d" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
  <Label Text="2600 Michelson" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
  <RelativeLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <ListView ItemsSource ="{Binding Meters}" HasUnevenRows="True" 
      RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
      RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}" >
    ...
    </ListView>
    <Button Text="Green button" BackgroundColor="#299164" Opacity="0.9"
        RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=0.5, Constant=-50}"
        RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor=1, Constant=-100}">
    </Button>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <Label Text="This label is not visible" TextColor="#0000ff"></Label>
<StackLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

I am still far from end design, but this is how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you use RelativeLayout. A StackLayout is not enough?

Comment: I need to have ListView and on top of it button (not below)

Comment: on top is "over"? and listview "under" the button? Have you a mokeup?

Comment: Exactly, I'll update question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can use a Grid. Try this code

XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestRelativeLayout.MyPage1"
             Title="TabbedPage">
             <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <Button Clicked="Handle_Clicked" Text = "Press">
            </Button>
                    <Grid VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Lista}" Grid.Row = "0" Grid.Column = "0" Grid.RowSpan = "2" Grid.ColumnSpan = "3" VerticalOptions = "FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding .}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
                <Button Text = "ButtonOver" Opacity="0.5" BackgroundColor = "Fuchsia" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column = "1"/>

            </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

this is the result

[image: The button is "OVER"]

Comment: I was a bit skeptical, but in the end it looks like exactly how I wonted. Thank you.

Comment: why are you skeptical? Grid is one of the powerful layout in Xamarin Forms. And RelativeLayout is better not to use it how you can see in this post http://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips